# OS X sample related to NSWindowController, NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, macos, transition, nswindowcontroller, nsviewcontroller

I am going to make an OS X application with several views and windows.

It has several screens - splash, login/register and the main screen(and so on).

I tried to use NSWindowControllers. However, it's so complex to use and I'm confused.

Where can I find the good sample related to view/window transitions?

Comment: Duplicate question here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889534/transition-between-windows-in-os-x
Please don't do this